# error mariadb from_unixtime

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

En la consulta

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1577833200,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Aparece como resultado "31-12-2019".
Mientras que en php:

```
echo date('d-m-Y',1577833200);
```

Arroja como resultado (correcto) 01-01-2020.

Agradecería alguna ayuda.
Gracias

Comment: Solución para codeIgniter4

/** * Set timezone in database as timezone in codeIgniter **/
$tz = Time::now()->getTimezone();
$tz = Time::now()->timezone;
$offset = (float) $tz->getOffset(new Time());
$format = '%+03d:%02u';
$timeZone = sprintf($format, $offset / 3600, abs($offset) % 3600 / 60);
\Config\Database::connect()->query("SET time_zone='{$timeZone}'");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso tiene pinta de ser por la diferencia de `timezone` que tienes entre el MySQL y el PHP.

Para averiguar cual tienes en MySQL ejecuta esta consulta a la base de datos:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
```

que seguramente te devolvera `SYSTEM` en ambas. Lo cual quiere decir que está usando el timezone del sistema desde donde corre el servidor MySQL.  En linux puedes averiguarlo mediante el comando `timedatectl` en terminal.

Y para averiguar cual tienes en PHP ejecuta:

```php
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

Luego comprueba que ambas son idénticas para asegurarte que no vas a sufrir desviaciones en tus cálculos, y si los hay aplica las correcciones oportunas mediante [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) en PHP (o en el servidor MySQL, pero eso dudo que sea viable si ya tienes los datos subidos y no quieres lios adicionales).

---

La solución aportada por el OP en los comentarios, basándose en mi respuesta, personalizada para su caso, ha sido finalmente esta:

```
 /** * Set timezone in database as timezone in codeIgniter **/
$tz = Time::now()->getTimezone();
$tz = Time::now()->timezone;
$offset = (float) $tz->getOffset(new Time());
$format = '%+03d:%02u';
$timeZone = sprintf($format, $offset / 3600, abs($offset) % 3600 / 60);
\Config\Database::connect()->query("SET time_zone='{$timeZone}'");
```

Comment: Gracias!
lo solucioné así:

$timeZone = sprintf('+%s:00',date_default_timezone_set(app_timezone()));    
 \Config\Database::connect()->query("SET time_zone='{$timeZone}'");

Comment: Ok, perfecto, me alegro!  Acabo de editar mi respuesta agregando tu aporte para darle más visibilidad para la comunidad.

Comment: Ahora ha evolucionado:

/**
     * Set timezone in database as timezone in codeIgniter
     **/
    
    $tz = Time::now()->getTimezone();
    $tz = Time::now()->timezone;
    $offset = (float) $tz->getOffset(new Time());
    $format = '%+03d:%02u';
    $timeZone = sprintf($format, $offset / 3600, abs($offset) % 3600 / 60);
    \Config\Database::connect()->query("SET time_zone='{$timeZone}'");

Comment: Gracias!  La acabo de agregar sustituyendo la anterior